# How do websites have various animated elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'd like to learn how to build animated areas on websites, like Aeria Games does on their website.

http://www.aeriagames.com/

When the page loads the top banner begins to animate, and then each banner rotation after that is also animated.

Does anyone know of a guide/tutorial to accomplish the same result?

Comment: That's a video on the background, embedded using <video> tag

Comment: you can use css, check this link for animations you can learn from it and make your own [Animation cheat sheet](http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/)

Comment: check out https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score -1):

You can use video (for .ogg, .webm, .mp4) embed (for .swf) or img (for .gif)
ex:

```
<video width="320" height="240">
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

or

```
<embed src="helloworld.swf">
```

or

```
<img src="animation.gif" alt="Animation" height="42" width="42">
```